# Replying to Alphanumeric SMS Sender Id

Tags: sms

I am looked through the documentation for over 30 sms vendors, not one supports replies through alphanumeric sender ids. I am wondering if this is technically possible at all? Or know of any vendors that provide this service? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

(I did this 20 years ago, but SMS didn't change that much over the years).

The chief problem here is that alphanumeric senders are typically used in mass communications scenario's, not 1 to 1 communication. Technically there's no reason for such a restriction. The SMS sender field has a format, either digits or alphanumeric characters, and that field is not specially restricted for replies.

Vendor suggestions are off-topic BTW.

Comment: thanks can you elaborate on how you were able to let users reply when the sender field is alphanumeric?

Comment: @Kelvin: Oh, I thought you meant that you _received_ a request from an ordinary phone, (typically sent to a short code), and then would reply with a alphanumeric sender address. No, these alphanumeric addresses are not valid phone numbers so you can't send _to_ them, neither originally nor in replies.